# Помогите пожалуйста довести до ума скрипт увеличения изображения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Может кто помочь переписать данный скрипт более адекватно ? Потому что на данный момент это все работает очень плохо =/ 
Суть заключается в том, что будут изображения различной ширины и высоты, но в основном приблизительно таких размеров как в codepen. 
При клику надо что бы происходил как бы зум изображения и что бы оно подгонялось по высоте окна просмотра и с левого края (м.б. небольшой отступ слева). 
Сама суть данной анимации в приложенном codepen показана, а вот как это все реализовать более жизнеспособно без понятия (Даже если я и смогу сам разобраться, то это займет у меня в разы больше времени чем я имею, галера не ждёт) ...

П.С. : По итогу это должно представлять из себя как бы открытие попапа: Происходит зум, а после его окончания справа появляется описание к изображению.

**Ссылка на CodePen :** https://codepen.io/thystruby/pen/mpEVvN?editors=1100

```
$(".zoom-img").click(function(){
    var i = $(this);
    var h = i.height();
    var w = i.width();
    var h1 = i.height();
    var w1 = i.width(); 
    $("#"+i.attr("zoom-box")).css({"display":"block","opacity":0});
    var sh = $("#"+i.attr("zoom-box")).height();
    var sw = $("#"+i.attr("zoom-box")+" img").width();
    var sposition = $("#"+i.attr("zoom-box")+" img").offset();
    var position = i.offset();
    var trans = 'scale('+sh/h+')';
    $('.main').css({
        'transform': trans,
        'left':'-'+(position.left*(sh/h))+'px',
        'top':'-'+(position.top*(sh/h))+'px'
    });

    i.closest("div").toggleClass("active");
    $(".actual img").css({
        "-webkit-filter" : "grayscale(100%)",
        "-moz-filter" : "grayscale(100%)",
        "filter" : "grayscale(100%)",
        "opacity" : 0.5
    });
    $(".actual.active img").css({
        "-webkit-filter" : "grayscale(0)",
        "-moz-filter" : "grayscale(0)",
        "filter" : "grayscale(0)",
        "opacity" : 1
    });
});
  $(".img-cont").click(function(){
    $(this).css({"display":"none","opacity":0});
    $(".main").css({
        'transform':"scale(1)",
        'padding':0,
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0
    });
    $(".zoom-img").closest("div").removeClass("active");
    $(".actual img").css({
        "-webkit-filter" : "grayscale(0)",
        "-moz-filter" : "grayscale(0)",
        "filter" : "grayscale(0)",
        "opacity" : 1
    });
});
```

Comment: Необходимо именно довести скрипт до ума? или можно использовать готовые решения? Если можно готовые, то вот пример http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/, можно еще нагуглить кучу

Comment: По самому скрипту: опишите в css нужные классы с трансформациями, а в js только меняйте их у блоков.

Comment: @Skywave По поводу magnific-popup - он не подойдет потому что решение должно представлять из себя именно зум с увеличением всех элементов. А вот предложение поставить заранее заготовленные классы кажется достаточно разумным. Буду пробовать дальше делать именно в этом направлении. Спасибо!